# How do I define a function inside of a class using C++?

Tags: c++

How do I define a function inside of a class using C++?

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted?

Comment: Because he's asking rediculous, vague, broad, random questions... look at his others. He goes from asking how to write an OS, or how to implement a new Windows shell, to what does `int main` mean in C++ and this one. In the last few days, he's worked on an OS, an AVI decoder, parsing HTML, SQL, WinSock programming, and bluetooth device drivers; yet doesn't know how to define a class in C++?  He's in a class where he has a requirement to get 500 SO reputation!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are 2 answers:

**1) Combining both the declaration and the definition:**

```
class C
{
public:
  //declaration and definition of f
  void f()
  {
  }

};
```

**2) Separating the declaration and the definition:**

```
class C
{
public:
  //declaration of f
  void f();
};

//definition of f
void C::f()
{
}
```

Typically in option #2 you would separate the declaration into a header file and the definition inside a source file.

Comment: That's the answer (+1). May as well accept it; no one will post any more, because that covers it all.

Comment: This is perfect if I could give you plus 10 I would :) tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Simple ans:when we write the function within the class with his body is known as function declaration and defination with in the class.

Defination of function outside the class:when we write the function name outside the class by the help of scoperesulation operator is called function defination outside the class.